# What does "ABC" class do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a class that inherits another class:

```
class ValueSum(SubQuery):
    output = IntegerField()
```

And *pycharm* is showing the following warning:

> Class ValueSum must implement all abstract methods

Then I `alt+enter` to add `ABC` to superclass. And my warning is gone. I have several questions:

- Should I always do this when writing a sub-class?
- What is the difference between manually implementing all the methods
  vs just using `ABC`?
- Does `ABC` add something to my code?

Comment: What's `SubQuery`?

Comment: `SubQuery` is a Django model expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SubQuery` is an abstract base class (per the [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)) with one or more abstract methods that you did not override. By adding `ABC` to the list of base classes, you defined `ValueSum` itself to be an abstract base class. That means you aren't forced to override the methods, but it also means you cannot instantiate `ValueSum` itself.

PyCharm is warning you ahead of time that you need to implement the abstract methods inherited from `SubQuery`; if you don't, you would get an error from Python when you actually tried to instantiate `ValueSum`.

---

As to what inheriting from `ABC` *does*, the answer is... not much. It's a convenience for setting the metaclass. The following are equivalent:

```
class Foo(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    ...
```

and

```
class Foo(abc.ABC):
    ...
```

The metaclass modifies `__new__` so that every attempt to create an instance of your class checks that the class has implemented all methods decorated with `@abstractmethod` in a parent class.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Abstract Base classes" or `abc.ABC` is a helper class

https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Here's a snippet of why they exist:

> The collections module has some concrete classes that derive from ABCs; these can, of course, be further derived. In addition, the `collections.abc` submodule has some ABCs that can be used to test whether a class or instance provides a particular interface, for example, if it is hashable or if it is a mapping.

A good example here: https://pymotw.com/2/abc/ | https://pymotw.com/3/abc/

From pymotw:

Forgetting to set the metaclass properly means the concrete implementations do not have their APIs enforced. To make it easier to set up the abstract class properly, a base class is provided that sets the metaclass automatically.

```
abc_abc_base.py
import abc


class PluginBase(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load(self, input):
        """Retrieve data from the input source
        and return an object.
        """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def save(self, output, data):
        """Save the data object to the output."""


class SubclassImplementation(PluginBase):

    def load(self, input):
        return input.read()

    def save(self, output, data):
        return output.write(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Subclass:', issubclass(SubclassImplementation,
                                  PluginBase))
    print('Instance:', isinstance(SubclassImplementation(),
                                  PluginBase))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the main point of abstract classes following to Object Oriented Programming (OOP). Classes, which inherit from an abstract class, need to implement all of the abstract methods. They don't need to, if they are abstract themselves. Those abstract methods are like method signatures of interfaces and don't have any implementation inside them. Therefor you cannot create a non-abtract class without impementing all the abstract methods. `ABC` is just a helper class to create new abstract classes by deriving from it. Here you can read more about abstract classes in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Based on your observation you mark `ValueSum` to be abstract. This means, that all subclasses of `ValueSum` need to implement the abstract methods of `ValueSum` and all its abstract superclasses, including `SubQuery`.

> I write class that abstracts from some class.

No. You wrote a class, which **inherits** from another.

> Should I always do this when I writing sub class?

No. Only if you want the class to be abstract.

> What is the difference between manually implementing all the methods vs just using ABC

In this case you are forwarding the implementation to all subclasses of `ValueSum`. Not using `ABC` will force you to implement the abstract methods inside of `ValueSum`.

> Does `ABC` add something to my code?

No. In any case, not more than using other classes / inheritation.